# How can I use awk to make substitutions using two files?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to use awk to search in the first txt spreadsheet based on the Title column and if it match change the second file with this line.

I was first trying to use comm but it does not work.
I could not find any similar topics out there. Can someone help me?

FILE1

```
Title   score   atividade
ZINC79350772    -8.435  1
ZINC71820127    -8.371  1
ZINC65370023    -8.265  1
ZINC13151660    -8.203  1
```

FILE2

```
ZINC79350772 -8.435 0
ZINC71820127 -8.371 0
ZINC65370023 -8.265 0
ZINC78807290 -8.256 0
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
ZINC79350772 -8.435 1
ZINC71820127 -8.371 1
ZINC65370023 -8.265 1
ZINC78807290 -8.256 0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Comment: I don't use `join` much but I kind of got this to work but it's a kludge since `-e 0` puts the missing zero back on: `join -e 0 -o 1.1 1.2 2.3 -a1 file2.txt <(sed 1d file1.txt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next} $1 in a{$3=a[$1]} 1' file1 file2

ZINC79350772 -8.435 1
ZINC71820127 -8.371 1
ZINC65370023 -8.265 1
ZINC78807290 -8.256 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this tested version a try:

```
(cat FILE1; printf "NEXT_FILE\n"; cat FILE2) | awk '{if ($1 ~ /NEXT_FILE/) {secondfile=1;} else if (!secondfile && NR>1) {score[$1]=$2; actividade[$1]=$3;} else if (secondfile) { if (score[$1]) {$2=score[$1]; $3=actividade[$1];} print;}}' > DESIRED_OUTPUT

cat DESIRED_OUTPUT
ZINC79350772 -8.435 1
ZINC71820127 -8.371 1
ZINC65370023 -8.265 1
ZINC78807290 -8.256 0
```

It is using associative arrays, as described in the famous [Awk - A Tutorial and Introduction - by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-58)

The associative arrays **score** and **actividade** are populated while reading the FILE1.

When the FILE2 is read, if the current title column is first encountered then it is printed, otherwise the values first found in FILE1 are printed.